# What is the argument -xi of zip doing?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, zip

When using the zip command on windows, what is the argument `-xi` doing?

```
C:\Users\mspg>zip
Copyright (C) 1990-2005 Info-ZIP
Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 2.31 (March 8th 2005). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
```

Also, how can I use it?

```
C:\temp>zip b.zip -xi a.txt 1>helloWorld.log
zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)
```

Comment: But before asking it is recommended to read the [documentation](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html) of the used application. `[-xi list]` is combined for `-x (exclude) or -i (include) options` or in other words `[-x exclude list] [-i include list]`. I have never used __info-Zip__ nor was this application ever installed on one of my machines. But I found the answer on your question in 3 minutes by visiting [info-Zip homepage](http://www.info-zip.org/Info-ZIP.html) and reading quickly about the options in linked online documentation. Please next time first read documentation before asking.

Comment: Thanks, already read the documentation. Including and excluding a file does not make sense to me. This is why I asked what is it actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual `-xi` option. The `[-xi list]` in the documentation is just (confusing) shorthand for `[-x list] [-i list]` - two separate possible options.